# Progress 12.2 - Concat rows with same ID

Tags: sql, database, bdd, openedge, progress-db

I use the database Progress 12.2 and I want to group rows with same id

For example I have

```
ID Code
1   PB
1   RO
```

And I want :

```
ID Code
1   PB, RO
```

This is my request :

```
SELECT id, code FROM table WHERE table.id = 1
```

I tried String_agg, Group_concat ... but nothing works. Anyone has an idea ?

Regards,

Comment: https://community.progress.com/s/article/000045898

Answer (score 0):

You can use someting like that;

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (ID Int, Code nvarchar(5))
INSERT INTO @TBL values (1 ,'PB'),(1 ,'RO')

SELECT DISTINCT
T1.ID,
CONCAT_STRING = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + T2.Code
          FROM @TBL T2
          WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM @TBL T1
```

The result will be like this;

[image]

Comment: Is this valid Progess SQL code?

Comment: I think no. It's not work for me

Answer (score 0):

What is the code you tried with GROUP_CONCAT?

Try this query:

```cs
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(code SEPARATOR ', ') AS code_list
FROM table
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY id
```

If this won't work, another solution is loading the codes into a variable before displaying:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE c_id          AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE c_concatenate AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

FOR EACH TABLE_name WHERE TABLE.id = 1 NO-LOCK:

    IF c_concatenate <> "" THEN 
        ASSIGN c_concatenate = c_concatenate + "," + TABLE.CODE.
    ELSE ASSIGN c_concatenate = TABLE.CODE.

END.

/* DISPLAY here */
```

Comment: Appears not to be supported by Progress.